# detecting overlap in my data files start and stop positions and separating them

Tags: perl

This script I'm working with is intended to looked a through a file and detect moments of overlap, all the overlapping positions are put into new files.

column 2 can be thought of as a start position and column 2 can be looked at as a stop position so in the example of

```
2 6 10 5
2 9 13 5
3 8 9 5
```

The first two lines would have overlap since the second starts at 9 and the first ends at 10 so they would be overlapped in the 9-10 position.
The third line does not have overlap however because the number in the first column is 3 and not 2 which is necessary criteria.

Now that you understand what is meant by overlap

The input in ARGV[0] is a file with is like

```
9   9000000 14100000    23
9   9000000 32800000    4
9   9000000 40200000    6
9   9000000 42400000    5
9   89600000    116700000   28
9   89600000    129300000   8
9   89600000    140273252   52
S   0   24900000    2
S   0   24900000    22
S   0   37500000    2
S   40000000 45000000 7
S   42500000 47000000 9
```

Given this file ARGV[1] by the end will end up having in it

```
9   9000000 14100000    23
9   89600000    116700000   28
S   0   24900000    2
S   40000000 45000000 7
```

This(which i will call z.txt later) will be passed to standard output

```
9   9000000 32800000    4
9   9000000 40200000    6
9   9000000 42400000    5
9   89600000    129300000   8
9   89600000    140273252   52
S   0   24900000    22
S   0   37500000    2
S   42500000 47000000 9
```

ARGV[3] is essentially a wc -l #file | awk '{print $1}'
of the file that ARGV[0] is

This is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# ARGV[0] is the name of the file which data will be read from(may have overlaps)
# ARGV[1] is the name of the file which will be produced that will have no overlaps
# ARGV[2] is the name of a directory
# ARGV[3] is the number of lines that ARGV[0] will contain
#The purpose of this script is to look through the data file and if there are overlaps then another layer is created
use warnings;
#use strict;

#Here I am just trying to open up my file in order to read from it
my $file = "./$ARGV[0]";
my @lines = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file -- $!";
    <$fh>;
};

#Here I am assignning a secon file that will contain the overlaps
my $file2 = "./$ARGV[2]/$ARGV[1]";
open(my $fh, ">", "$file2")
        or die "Can't open > $file2: $!";

# For each element compare all following ones, but cut out
# as soon as there's no overlap since data is sorted
my $i = 0;
while ($i < $ARGV[3]) {
        my @ref_fields = split('\s+', $lines[$i]);
#This line is printed to the file handle because it shouldn't have any overlaps so everyline in this file will not overlap with any other
        print $fh "$ref_fields[0]", "\t", $ref_fields[1], "\t", $ref_fields[2], "\t", $ref_fields[3], "\n";
#The script then looks at the lines following the line just looked at
        for my $j ($i+1..$ARGV[3]) {
                my @curr_fields = split /\s+/, $lines[$j];
#if the line does overlap then print it to standard output
                if ( $ref_fields[2] > $curr_fields[1] ) {
                        print $curr_fields[0], "\t", $curr_fields[1], "\t", $curr_fields[2], "\t", $curr_fields[3], "\n";
                }
                else {
#if it doesn't, since all the file is sorted the overlaps are done with
                        $i=$j;
                        last;
                }
        }
        $i++;
}
```

Once this script is done then the standard output can be put in a file and run through the script again, so that the overlaps can be weeded out again

unfortunately with my original ARGV[0] that has about 1300 lines, it produces about 6000 lines of output to standard output somehow

Sorry if this is confusing, it's a tricky concept for me but ask any questions if you have them

Thank-you

Extra example

If z.txt is run through this code again it should print to ARGV[1]

```
9   9000000 32800000    4
9   89600000    129300000   8
S   0   24900000    22
S   42500000 47000000 9
```

And standard output it should print

```
9   9000000 40200000    6
9   9000000 42400000    5
9   89600000    140273252   52
S   0   37500000    2
```

Comment: Are you asking us to debug your code, or do you have a specific question?

Comment: Yes a debug, I'm wondering why this happens "with my original ARGV[0] that has about 1300 lines, it produces about 6000 lines of output to standard output somehow"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is a mistake with this assignment: $i=$j; This way you overshoot one input line when an overlap occurs.
Secondly, the inner cycle list should be ($i+1..$ARGV[3]-1), not ($i+1..$ARGV[3]).
Thirdly, you need to skip over processed lines when there are no overlap till the end of file. 
Otherwise you get the same lines over and over.
It can be done like this (note $new_i):

```
while ($i < $ARGV[3]) {
...
    my $new_i=$i;
    for my $j ($i+1..$ARGV[3]-1) {
        $new_i=$j;
        ...
        else {
            # you don't need this assignment
            # $i=$j;
            last;
        }
    }
    $i=$new_i+1;
}
```